# C#: Referencing an instance of a class that was made in another class

Tags: c#, class, instances

I need some help with C#.

Let's say I have 3 classes. MainMenu, Form1 and Data.
I have created an instance of Data (referenced as StoreData) in MainMenu.

```
public partial class MainMenu : Form
    {
        public Data StoreData = new Data();
    }
```

I want to be able to access this instance of StoreData in Form1. How do I reference it or import it?

Comment: maybe you can make Data as a static member of class MainMenu?

Comment: Can you expand your question to include how Form1 is used/related, please?

Comment: @Polly, why would they want to make it static? That would mean that if there were ever two instances of MainMenu they would refer to the same StoreData object. If you have a reference to your MainMenu object, you would be able to do something like myMainMenuForm.StoreData. Otherwise, if MainMenu created Form1, you could pass it on the constructor like new Form1(this.Data);

Comment: `StoreData` is public, so as long as you have a reference to the `MainMenu` instance you can just reference the property too? e.g. `myMainMenu.StoreData`

Comment: In the example you gave, you're creating a default value for an instance variable, but not ever instantiating the class (so there *are* no instances whose variables you might access). Create a `MainMenu` - for example `MainMenu mmenu = new MainMenu();` and then access its `StoreData` parameter (`mmenu.StoreData`).

Comment: @AdamG, the question is not clear. My comment is one way of solving the problem

Comment: Ok MainMenu is the main menu and there are variables such as Difficulty and Username, that I want to store in an instance of Data. Form1 is the game and I want to reflect the data stored from Data onto the form. If this makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

You can either

- Make `StoreData` static  in a static class `MyAWesomeStatic` and call `MyAWesomeStatic.StoreData` or even in `MainMenu` class iteself.
- Pass a reference of `StoreData` to `Form1` either via the constructor or a property when you create it.
- or pass a reference of `MainMenu` to `form1` and call `mainMenu.StoreData` when needed.

However, another option might be to use [*Dependency Injection (DI)*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) and [*Loosely Couple*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loose_coupling) all this. Have a *Singleton* instance and pass the in-memory *Data Store* as some sort of *Service* (which is what the cool kids might do).

**Update**

> Sorry, still at the beginning stages of learning C#. What does it mean
>   to make a class static?

Given your current level of knowledge and all-things-being-equal, i think the easiest approach might be just pass in a reference

```
public class Form1
{

    public Data StoreData { get; set; }
}

...

var form = new Form1();
form.StoreData = StoreData;
form.Show();
```

Comment: Sorry, still at the beginning stages of learning C#. What does it mean to make a class static?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to reference one class within another class (and don't want to make anything `static`), **composition** is one way to go.

You want to reference field of `MainForm` in `Form1`, so you want to reference `MainForm` itself. Thus, you need to create field in `Form1` of `MainForm` type:

```
public class Form1 : Form
{
    ...
    public MainForm mf { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Now, you can access `StordeData` with `mf.StordeData` within `Form1`.

Comment: You're suggesting this without adequate context. What if `MainForm` is to be used/referenced elsewhere by other classes? These semantics make a certain assumption. Possibly a wrong one.

Comment: I should add, possibly a right one. I like the composition approach, just need to make sure it's used at the right time.

Answer (score 0):

You could make StoreData static in a static class, something like this:

```
public static class Form1
{ 
    public static Data StoreData { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your `StoreData` class have one property

```
public class StoreData
        {
            public int MyProperty { get; set; } 
        }
```

Add static property to your mainform.cs and assign value to MyProperty = 1

```
    public partial class MainMenu : Form
        {
            public static StoreData Data { get; set; }   //static property

            private void MainMenu_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                Data = new StoreData { MyProperty = 1 };
            }
        }
```

And access your StoreData property inside Form1.cs like

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var id = MainMenu.Data.MyProperty;
        }

    }
```

Try once may it help you

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: @Kidsnd274, check out solution added with result, may it help you :)